# Joomla 500 Error

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, localhost

I am trying to log into my Joomla administrator on my Localhost but I keep getting a 500 error.

I've tried loads of things:

Changed file permissions of:

```
chmod 777 error.php,
chmod 775 cache, logs adminstrator etc
```

I've tried uncommenting `# RewriteBase /` in my htaccess

I've changed the path in my *configuration.php* to:

```
public $log_path = './logs';
public $tmp_path = './tmp';
```

I have also checked my apached error logs and it is coming back with the following:

```
[22-May-2014 14:17:49 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning: fopen(./logs/error.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mydir/libraries/joomla/log/loggers/formattedtext.php on line 248
[22-May-2014 14:17:49 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning: fputs() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mydir/libraries/joomla/log/loggers/formattedtext.php on line 254
```

Any help much appreciated
,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the directory

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mydir/libraries/joomla/log/loggers/logs
```

Then try again

Comment: thank you for your reply Chris. I've tried your suggestion and unfortunately I am still getting the same error.  The error log is also coming back with the lines I mentioned above and as a result of adding the new logs directory, nothing has been written to it

Comment: Try changing
 public $log_path = './logs';
to
 public $log_path = '/full/path/to/directory/that/definitely/exists/logs';

Comment: Tried that for both the logs and tmp directory.  Still same issue

Comment: It's a windows machine by the look of it, so you may need to put the drive name in

Comment: Ok I think I may be getting somewhere. The path was correct in the configuration file so I did chmod 777 to allow writing to the directory.  Now when I try to login to Joomla admin, I am getting an error that my username and password are incorrect, so I am assuming I'll get that from phpmyadmin?